# Extending the shutdown timeout for BackgroundService

Tags: c#, windows-services, settimeout, .net-5

I have a class that derives from `BackgroundService` and is added as a hosted service in my `Startup.cs`. In the `StopAsync()` method I'm doing some pretty long tasks. Some of them are not able to finish because of the `ShutdownTimeout` option in the `Host.cs` ([link to source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/97f0e8a5e4110244224fbc115c8d3dc5c44a360f/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L67)) class.
My solution to fix it was to set `ShutdownTimeout` with `IWebHostBuilder.UseShutdownTimeout()`, but it doesn't have an impact on the background service.

```
    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseShutdownTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .UseWindowsService();
    }
```

Is there a way to set `UseShutdownTimeout` for the `BackgroundService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is

```
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.Configure<HostOptions>(opts => opts.ShutdownTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }
```

I think it is found in the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection package. From the code you are posting it looks like you are using a webhost which is different to Windows Service or console application.